# Go synchronization and concurrency model

Tags: go, concurrency, synchronization, channel

I'm a new Go learner, and I'm following [gobyexample.com](https://gobyexample.com) to learn the basics. When I reach the "closing channels" section, the tutorial inserts this code snippet (I'll remove original comments):

```golang
    package main

    import "fmt"

    func main() {
        jobs := make(chan int, 5)
        done := make(chan bool)

       go func() {
           for {
               j, more := <-jobs
               if more {
                   fmt.Println("received job", j)
               } else {
                   fmt.Println("received all jobs")
                   done <- true
                   return
               }
           }
       }()

       for j := 1; j <= 18; j++ {
           jobs <- j
           fmt.Println("sent job", j)
       }
       close(jobs)
       fmt.Println("sent all jobs")

       <-done
    }
```

The original code was setting a 3 instead of a 18 in the job sender loop.

Executing this code in [play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org) it is what I don't fully understand. It always outputs the following:

```
sent job 1
sent job 2
sent job 3
sent job 4
sent job 5
received job 1
received job 2
received job 3
received job 4
received job 5
received job 6
sent job 6
sent job 7
sent job 8
sent job 9
sent job 10
sent job 11
sent job 12
received job 7
received job 8
received job 9
received job 10
received job 11
received job 12
received job 13
sent job 13
sent job 14
sent job 15
sent job 16
sent job 17
sent job 18
sent all jobs
received job 14
received job 15
received job 16
received job 17
received job 18
received all jobs
```

So I understand that the "queue" of a channel (I'm aware this terminology is not the most accurate, but for the purpose of learning myself it is what I understand about what a channel is) is of size 5 so the first 10 log messages are fine for me.

But how can be the message 6 and 13 be output their reception prior than their actual sending? How can be 7 messages sent in a row, if the channel size is 5? What am I missing from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goroutines run concurrently, therefore they also print to stdout concurrently (i.e. out-of-order). Moreover, fmt.Print APIs are buffered, so your prints are not actually prited immediately as they are called. This happens also in other languages.

This is why you cannot derive the real concurrent execution of goroutines from the messages in stdout.

Comment: The bit about "fmt.Print APIs are buffered" is what I missed. Thank you very much

Comment: The fmt.Print functions do write to the output when they are called.  The functions use a buffer for constructing the output, but that buffer is written to stdout before the function returns.

Comment: @CeriseLimón, correct. The Go stdlib does not buffer to os.Stdout, but the OS probably does. I should have said it better.

Comment: Buffering has nothing to do with the output order observed by OP.  Regarding comment about other languages: Go is different from most other languages in that the Go fmt functions never buffer output written directly to stdout.

Answer (score 2):

> But how can be the message 6 and 13 be output their reception prior than their actual sending?

We only know `fmt.Println("received job", j)` was printed before `fmt.Println("sent job", j)` was printed, and this is plausible in concurrent working code.

> How can be 7 messages sent in a row, if the channel size is 5?

Again, because we dont know exactly which statement prints out first, this can be expected. The Queue can already be reduced and we still are printing.